# How to colorize php8 annotations?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```php
class LuckyController
{
    #[Route('/lucky/number/{max}', name: 'app_lucky_number')]
    public function number(int $max): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, $max);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I need to colorize words like "Route" and "name" of this examle in my custom theme, or colorize full annotation line.

I've tried to colorize "annotation" and "annotations" foreground, but it didn't work

```json
  "tokenColors": [
    {
      "name": "annoColor",
      "scope": ["annotation"],
      "settings": { "foreground": "#116062" }
    },
```